# Removing class of nested list elements based off click on outer list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have currently got this structure:

```
<ul id="topic_categories">
    <li><a href="">Type 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Type 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Type 3</a>
        <ul class="sub_topic_categories">
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">A</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">B</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">C</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">D</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">E</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">F</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a class="tooltip" href="">G</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Type4</a>
        <ul class="sub_topic_categories">
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">A</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">B</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">C</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">D</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">E</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="tooltip" href="">F</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a class="tooltip" href="">G</a><a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically what I want to do is;

1. First `li a` element within first `UL` is clicked. A class of `active` is added to the list element. I've done this so far using`$(this).parents('li').addClass("active");`
2. The next `UL` `sub_topic_category` is displayed(I've done this via CSS and it works) depending on which list element in active.
3. This is the part I am stuck at. I now need to make only list elements within the `sub_topic_category` displayed change class. When one list element `a` tag is clicked the class `active` is added to `li` parent of link clicked and the previous `active` class is removed WITHIN THAT SUB TOPIC LIST ONLY.

---

So for example in the code shown I have `Type4` set as active within the first `UL`. The second list is displayed `sub_topic_categories` with the first list element (as seen on the browser) set to active via hard-coded HTML. When I say Click on `A` I want `active` removed from the list element `G` and then added to `A`. This must only affect this `sub_topic_category` list.

I hope I have explained this well. At the moment I have

```
$('#topic_categories li ul.sub_topic_categories li.active').removeClass('active');
```

which works but it removes the active elements found in the `Type3` sub_topic_categories list as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this on click of `A`-

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active')
```

Demo `------->` http://jsfiddle.net/NrGGz/